# How to create 3d plot over hexagonal region

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I'm trying to plot the energy levels of graphene over the hexagonal Brillouin zone. So far I have plotted the energy levels using the code shown below. I then tried to edit my code using the method outlined [`here`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72932/plotting-energy-dispersion-on-a-hexagonal-brillouin-zone).

The plot looks good other than the blue hue overlaying the points so I was wondering how to get rid of that. I was also wondering how i could adapt this to be a surface plot as replacing ListPointPlot3D with ListSurfacePlot3D doesnt seem to work.

```
a1 = {0, 1/Sqrt[3]};
a2 = {-1/2, -1/(2*Sqrt[3])};
a3 = {1/2, -1/(2*Sqrt[3])};
kvec = {kx, ky};

nvalue = 1;
{{-2*t*(Cos[kvec . a1 - phi] + Cos[kvec . a2 - phi] + 
     Cos[kvec . a3 - phi]), 
  Exp[I*kvec . a1] + Exp[I*kvec . a2] + 
   Exp[I*kvec . a3]}, {Exp[-I*kvec . a1] + Exp[-I*kvec . a2] + 
   Exp[-I*kvec . a3], -2*
   t*(Cos[kvec . a1 + phi] + Cos[kvec . a2 + phi] + 
     Cos[kvec . a3 + phi])}};
graphenehamiltonian [kx_, ky_, t_, phi_] = % ;

kxrange = N[Range[-2*Pi + 2*Pi/100, 2*Pi - 2*Pi/100, 4*Pi/100]];
kyrange = N[Range[-2*Pi + 2*Pi/100, 2*Pi - 2*Pi/100, 4*Pi/100]];

f = Interpolation[
  Table[{a, 2 Pi*{Cos[a], Sin[a]}}, {a, -\[Pi], \[Pi], \[Pi]/3}], 
  InterpolationOrder -> 1];

eigsys = 
 Table[N[
   Eigensystem[
    graphenehamiltonian[kxrange[[i]], kyrange[[j]], tval, 
     phival]]], {i, 100}, {j, 100}];
eigvals = eigsys[[All, All, 1]];
eigvecs = eigsys[[All, All, 2]];
band1 = ListPointPlot3D[
  Table[{kxrange[[i]], kyrange[[k]], eigvals[[i]][[k]][[j]]}, {i, 
     100}, {k, 100}, {j, 2*nvalue}][[All, All, 1, All]], 
  RegionFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y, z}, Norm@{x, y} <= Norm@f[ArcTan[y, x]]], 
  ColorFunction -> "Pastel"];
band2 = ListPointPlot3D[
  Table[{kxrange[[i]], kyrange[[k]], eigvals[[i]][[k]][[j]]}, {i, 
     100}, {k, 100}, {j, 2*nvalue}][[All, All, 2, All]], 
  RegionFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y, z}, Norm@{x, y} <= Norm@f[ArcTan[y, x]]], 
  ColorFunction -> "Pastel"];

Show[band1, band2]
```

Comment: What is `tval`, `phival` ? Please copy your code from this page to a new notebook and evaluate it with a fresh kernel in order to determine what doesn't evaluate.

Comment: Hi, sorry i forgot to include those but including tval=0, phival=0 in the code should suffice as those values are arbitrary.

Answer (score 5):

The answer to the first part of the question is the option `RegionBoundaryStyle -> None`. The answer to the second part of the question is: `ListSurfacePlot3D`  does not seem to able to create a meaningful surface even when using data on such a block-structured grid. A possible solution is to create the surface manually using polygons. I added a working minimal example based on the code provided in the question. I simplified the rather convoluted `RegionFunction` by using `hexRegion=Region[RegularPolygon[2 \[Pi], 6]]` to parametrize the hexagon. Additionally I specified a color function to ensure unified coloring across the different plots.

```
a1={0,1/Sqrt[3]};
a2={-1/2,-1/(2*Sqrt[3])};
a3={1/2,-1/(2*Sqrt[3])};
kvec={kx,ky};

nvalue=1;
{{
  -2*t*(Cos[kvec.a1-phi]+Cos[kvec.a2-phi]+Cos[kvec.a3-phi]),
  Exp[I*kvec.a1]+Exp[I*kvec.a2]+Exp[I*kvec.a3]
},{
  Exp[-I*kvec.a1]+Exp[-I*kvec.a2]+Exp[-I*kvec.a3],
  -2*t*(Cos[kvec.a1+phi]+Cos[kvec.a2+phi]+Cos[kvec.a3+phi])
}};
graphenehamiltonian[kx_,ky_,t_,phi_]=%;

kxrange=N[Range[-2*Pi+2*Pi/100,2*Pi-2*Pi/100,4*Pi/100]];
kyrange=N[Range[-2*Pi+2*Pi/100,2*Pi-2*Pi/100,4*Pi/100]];

tval=0;
phival=0;
eigsys=Table[N[Eigensystem[graphenehamiltonian[kxrange[[i]],kyrange[[j]],tval,phival]]],{i,100},{j,100}];
eigvals=eigsys[[All,All,1]];
eigvecs=eigsys[[All,All,2]];

hexRegion=Region[RegularPolygon[2\[Pi],6]];
data=Table[{kxrange[[i]],kyrange[[k]],eigvals[[i]][[k]][[j]]},{i,100},{k,100},{j,2*nvalue}];
cfun=ColorData["Pastel"][(#3+2.5)/6]&;
```

First the `ListPointPlot3D` plots:

```
band1=ListPointPlot3D[data[[All,All,1,All]],RegionFunction->Function[{x,y,z},{x,y}\[Element]hexRegion],ColorFunction->cfun,RegionBoundaryStyle->None,ColorFunctionScaling->False];
band2=ListPointPlot3D[data[[All,All,2,All]],RegionFunction->Function[{x,y,z},{x,y}\[Element]hexRegion],ColorFunction->cfun,RegionBoundaryStyle->None,ColorFunctionScaling->False];

plot1=Show[band1,band2]
```

> [image: ListPointPlot3D]

and here the manually generated surface plot (with 50% opacity overlaying the previous plot):

```
band1polygons=Table[With[{
  a={kxrange[[i]],kyrange[[k]],eigvals[[i]][[k]][[1]]},
  b={kxrange[[i+1]],kyrange[[k]],eigvals[[i+1]][[k]][[1]]},
  c={kxrange[[i+1]],kyrange[[k+1]],eigvals[[i+1]][[k+1]][[1]]},
  d={kxrange[[i]],kyrange[[k+1]],eigvals[[i]][[k+1]][[1]]}},
If[Mean[{a,b,c,d}[[All,{1,2}]]]\[Element]hexRegion,{EdgeForm[],cfun[0,0,Mean[{a,b,c,d}[[All,3]]]],Polygon[{a,b,c,d}]},Nothing]],{i,99},{k,99}];

band2polygons=Table[With[{
  a={kxrange[[i]],kyrange[[k]],eigvals[[i]][[k]][[2]]},
  b={kxrange[[i+1]],kyrange[[k]],eigvals[[i+1]][[k]][[2]]},
  c={kxrange[[i+1]],kyrange[[k+1]],eigvals[[i+1]][[k+1]][[2]]},
  d={kxrange[[i]],kyrange[[k+1]],eigvals[[i]][[k+1]][[2]]}},
If[Mean[{a,b,c,d}[[All,{1,2}]]]\[Element]hexRegion,{EdgeForm[],cfun[0,0,Mean[{a,b,c,d}[[All,3]]]],Polygon[{a,b,c,d}]},Nothing]],{i,99},{k,99}];

Show[{plot1,Graphics3D[{Opacity[.5],band1polygons}],Graphics3D[{Opacity[.5],band2polygons}]}]
```

> [image: Surface plot]

The edges of the surface a a bit rough since I just excluded polygons outside the hexagon without modifying or detecting edges. Another (probably cleaner solution) would be to render all Polygons and use `ClipPlanes` for `Graphics3D` to generate the hexagonal area:

```
Table[Sqrt[3]\[Pi]{Sin[phi],Cos[phi],0},{phi,0+Pi/6,2Pi+Pi/6,Pi/3}];
hexPlanes=Table[InfinitePlane[{%[[i]],%[[i+1]],%[[i]]+{0,0,1}}],{i,1,6}];

band1polygons=Table[With[{
  a={kxrange[[i]],kyrange[[k]],eigvals[[i]][[k]][[1]]},
  b={kxrange[[i+1]],kyrange[[k]],eigvals[[i+1]][[k]][[1]]},
  c={kxrange[[i+1]],kyrange[[k+1]],eigvals[[i+1]][[k+1]][[1]]},
  d={kxrange[[i]],kyrange[[k+1]],eigvals[[i]][[k+1]][[1]]}},
{EdgeForm[],cfun[0,0,Mean[{a,b,c,d}[[All,3]]]],Polygon[{a,b,c,d}]}],{i,99},{k,99}];

band2polygons=Table[With[{
  a={kxrange[[i]],kyrange[[k]],eigvals[[i]][[k]][[2]]},
  b={kxrange[[i+1]],kyrange[[k]],eigvals[[i+1]][[k]][[2]]},
  c={kxrange[[i+1]],kyrange[[k+1]],eigvals[[i+1]][[k+1]][[2]]},
  d={kxrange[[i]],kyrange[[k+1]],eigvals[[i]][[k+1]][[2]]}},
{EdgeForm[],cfun[0,0,Mean[{a,b,c,d}[[All,3]]]],Polygon[{a,b,c,d}]}],{i,99},{k,99}];

Show[{Graphics3D[band1polygons~Join~band2polygons, ClipPlanes->hexPlanes]}]
```

> [image: ClipPlanes]